# LARAVEL & VUE: How can I get the API_TOKEN of the logged in user with an API request?

Tags: laravel, api, session, vue.js, axios

I have a SPA using VUE and LARAVEL 5.8
I have setup an API_TOKEN associated to the logged in user. Everything works fine right after the login. I get the API_TOKEN, I save it into a var and I send it together with the Axios request. In Laravel I have a middleware that is taking care of the token and comparing it with the one setup on the logged in user.

the problem though occur when session expires. Because I still can navigate the private pages and make API requests to save and delete content. This is  possible I think because I still have the same API_TOKEN saved in the var and the middleware apparently doesn't get that the session is expired.

So I want to obtain the API_TOKEN every time I'm doing an Ajax, request so when the session expires, I won't get the token and therefore, I won't be able to complete the request.

**This is my setup.**

`web.php` is where I have the only php route that points to a `singlePageController`:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Then in the `singlePageController` I return the view:

```
class SinglePageController extends Controller
    {
        public function index() {
        return view('app', ['loggedUser' => auth()->user()]);
    }
}
```

Then I have the `api.php` where I have the API routes. As you can see at the end I have the middleware to make it private. Just to make an example this is the one I use for updating the content:

```
Route::put('event/update/{slug}', 'EventController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Then the related controller of that API route:

```
public function update(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $event = Event::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $event->title = $request->input('title');

    return new EventResource($event);
 }
```

And in the end this is the Resource I use to define what and how the API data is going to be displayed:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    // return parent::toArray($request);

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'curator' => $this->curator,
        'featured_image' => $this->featured_image,
        'body' => $this->body,
        'date' => $this->date
    ];
 }
```

So this above is the flow I have. Then when I do an axios call to update the content, I'm doing something like:

```
    axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/event/update/' + this.$route.params.slug + '?api_token=' + this.isLogged.apiToken,
            data: dataToSave,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })  
        .then((response) => {
            this.getNotification('Success: The Event has been saved');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.getNotification('Error: Impossible saving the event');
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Do you know how to make it? or if there is a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: can you post your middleware code?

Comment: It's this one https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#protecting-routes.
But I have no idea where to find the code cause it's built in Laravel and apperently it's not in one of the middleware that Laravel has. I added my current setup

Answer (score 0):

you and do like, your login method should like this.

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success = $user->createToken(config('app.name'))->accessToken;
            return response()->json(["token" => $success, 'status' => 200]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => "Email or Password do not match"], 401);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added my current setup

Comment: did you get access token ?

Comment: The token is not the problem. I was to check If the session is valid while doing an Ajax request. It’s about session, not the token.

Comment: @rolfo85 to check if session is valid you can use auth middleware in route, to check token is valid you can use api:auth middleware in api routes

Comment: It doesn't work. I wrapped the update API route into this Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'auth']], function() { ... but if I delete the session manually and I try to save it right away, it saves with no errors. If I invert and I put in the middleware 'auth' first, I get the 401 error. I think this is why within the Ajax request there is no session info, so when the auth middleware is checking for it, it doesn't find anything and it throws 401.